# Azure Subscription not found - new portal

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-functions

I get "Subscription not found" when trying to add resource, however, my subscription exists.

I tried this:
http://www.garethjones294.com/azure-portal-no-subscriptions-found/

When I login to https://manage.windowsazure.com/ it says that Subscription has moved to https://portal.azure.com, and I cannot set it.

I've tried to set the correct directory as stated in
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/billing/billing-no-subscriptions-found - I am already the owner and Azure deployment says: SubscriptionDoesNotExists.

Any ideas?

Comment: Adding a screenshot might help here.

Comment: @ShridharR.Kulkarni said, could you show some error screenshot? Also, could you create other resources, like VM, public IP address?

Comment: @ShridharR.Kulkarni You have your subscription owner role like this [screenshot](https://imgur.com/a/aSWXI). You also could open a free ticket, refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-supportability/resource-manager-core-quotas-request).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please ensure your subscription role is `Owner` like following screenshot.

[image]

If you have correct role, I suggest you could open a free ticket to Azure. Please refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-supportability/resource-manager-core-quotas-request).

Hope it helps.

Comment: I got MSFT to resolve it for me. It seems that migrating from old to new portal I seem to be not an owner. It's fixed now.