# SubscriptionNotFound while creating an azure function app

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I get the following error "code": "SubscriptionNotFound", when trying to create a Function App. Any idea?

Thanks!

Comment: Same as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47492736/azure-subscription-not-found-new-portal, seems like something is wrong today. Was it working before?

Comment: No, just got a free subscription account today, and I have the "owner" role.

Comment: @Amir Could you show some error screenshots?

Comment: @Amir If you have your subscription `Owner` role, like this [screenshot](https://imgur.com/a/aSWXI), you could open a free ticket, refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-supportability/resource-manager-core-quotas-request).

Comment: Thanks @ShengbaoShui-MSFT! The problem is resolved.

Comment: @Amir Hi, how do you solve it?

Comment: @ShengbaoShui-MSFT it was resolved by Microsoft. Thanks!

Comment: The answer is below - subscriptions -> IAM -> add owner role.

Answer (score 0):

If you are a new user , you need to login admin account and go to subscriptions> I AM roles and assign the subscription to the new user as contributor or owner or any role which will allow you to create app function . It might solve the problem.

Comment: This is the answer people.

Comment: @Marc ha , after 2 years . Hope it helped .